# Python error "Ordinal not in range" with accents

Tags: python

I'm scraping a table from the Internet and saving as a CSV file. There are characters with French accents in the text, resulting in a unicode error on save:

```
 UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'd like to find an elegant solution for saving accented characters that I can apply to any situation. I've sometimes used the following:

```
 encode('ascii','ignore')
```

but it doesn't work this time, for reasons unknown. I'm also trying to replace the `<sup>` tags in a cell, so I'm converting it using `str()` first.

Here's the pertinent part of my code:

```
 data = [
      str(td[0]).split('<sup')[0].split('>')[1].split('<')[0],
      td[1].getText()
 ]
 output.append(data)

 csv_file = csv.writer(open('savedFile.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')

 for line in output:
      csv_file.writerow(line)
```

Comment: If you want Unicode, don't use the `'ascii'` codec.

Comment: I'm not picky about how it's encoded, I just need to save it without getting an error. Encoding to `ascii` has solved the issue before, but not this time.

Comment: `ascii` codec can't encode anything outside the 128 characters of the basic ASCII table. And it's the default in python 2.x.

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue, it tries to sweep the issue under the rug (`'ignore'`).  Sometimes this leaves a visible lump under the rug (your error) instead.  Do it right; if you want Unicode, use a Unicode encoding.

Comment: I agree that it was a bandaid solution. How do I use Unicode encoding, though?

Answer (score 0):

If `td[0]` is `u"a<sup>b</sup>c"` :

`td[0].split('<sup')` is `u"a"`.

`td[0].partition('>')[2].split('<')[0]` is `u"b"`.

`td[0][td[0].rindex('>') + 1:]` is `u"c"`.

If this kind of string indexing and matching is too simple you might consider createing a regular expression and matching it against the text in the html tag:

```
import re
r = re.compile("[^<]*<sup>([^<]*)</sup>")
m = r.match("some<sup>text</sup>")
print(m.groups()[0])
```

Comment: The problem with that is `.getText()` strips the HTML tags, including `<sup>`, so the value inside `<sup>` remains.

Comment: Perhaps if I could strip the HTML tags another way, everything would stay in unicode and wouldn't produce the error.

Answer (score 0):

The `csv.reader()` and `csv.writer()` require the files opened in binary mode.  You should also close the file at the end.  Therefore, you should write it like:

```
f = open('output.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

for row in output:
    writer.writerow(row)

f.close()
```

Or you can use the `with` construct when using newer versions of Python:

```
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in output:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

... and the file will be closed automatically.

Anyway, the csv.writer() expects the row composed of the byte sequences (not Unicode strings).  If you have Unicode strings, convert them using .encode('utf-8'):

```
    for row in output:
        encoded_row = [s.encode('utf-8') for s in row]
        writer.writerow(encoded_row)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help with this, but that still returned the same error. Perhaps I should post the full code to see if there are other things I'm doing wrong along the way. Meantime, saving to JSON works fine since, I'm gathering, it doesn't need Unicode.

Comment: So, are you using Unicode strings or not? Or better to ask (as you are calling `str()`, are you using Python 3 or Python 2.  If Python 2, you should not call .encode() at all as `str()` does not return Unicode strings.

Comment: Removing all references to `str()` and `.getText()` prevents the error from showing. I should probably try stripping HTML tags using another method. Thanks for your help.